# Libxml2: Outputting XML element with attribute and content

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I'm using the libxml2 XMLTextWriter API (of which an official example is provided [here](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/testWriter.c)) to output XML, but can't find any examples or see how to produce an element with both attributes and content, like so:

```
 <MyElement myAttrib="x">Content</MyElement>
```

Surprisingly, I'm not seeing any questions on SO that address this. Maybe because people just output XML themselves rather than using a library.

The C code I have so far is:

```
if (xmlTextWriterStartElement(writer, BAD_CAST "MyElement") < 0
    || xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute(writer, BAD_CAST "myAttrib", "x") < 0
    || somehow print out content < 0
    || xmlTextWriterEndElement(writer) < 0)
{
   // Handle error
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [xmlTextWriterWriteFormatString](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/tdb/_doc.php/userg/sw/libxml2/doc/html/html/libxml-xmlwriter.html#xmlTextWriterWriteFormatString) or [xmlTextWriterWriteString](http://xmlTextWriterWriteString) will do the trick. Somehow I missed those at first 
when looking through the API details.

Rather than delete, I'll leave here as this info might be useful for others looking for this info quickly.

Example:

```
if (xmlTextWriterStartElement(writer, BAD_CAST "MyElement") < 0
    || xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute(writer, BAD_CAST "myAttrib", "x") < 0
    || xmlTextWriterWriteString(writer, "Content") < 0
    || xmlTextWriterEndElement(writer) < 0)
{
   // Handle error
}
```

Update: Tested and confirmed this works.